# unexpected token in expression or statement - powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

```
## To run the script
# .\get_status.ps1 -Hostname <host> -Service_Action <action> -Service_Name <name>

#$Hostname = "hostname"
#$Service_Action = "Get-Service"
#$Service_Name = "service_name"

param(
    [string]$Hostname,
    [string]$Service_Action,
    [string]$Service_Name
)

$ScriptBlockContent = {
    param($Service_Action, $Service_Name)
    & $Service_Action $Service_Name
    }

# user credentials
$Username = "username"
$Password = "password"

# To avoid Manual entry of Username and Password
$Secure_String = convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force
$User_cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $Username, $Secure_String

# Create a Session
$pso = New-PSSessionOption -NoMachineProfile
$sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Hostname -SessionOption $pso -credential $User_cred

#Run a powershell script in the session.
Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlockContent -ArgumentList $Service_Action, $Service_Name

# Remove session
Remove-PSSession $sess
```

To run the script:

```
.\<script_name>.ps1 -Hostname <host> -Service_Action <action> -Service_Name <name>
```

For ex: Service Action is- Get-Service, Stop-Service, Start-Service
and then Name

```
Command: Get-Service Servicename
```

I am getting an error:
Unexpected token in expression or statement on this line of code:

```
$ScriptBlockContent = {
        param($Service_Action, $Service_Name)
        $Service_Action $Service_Name # here is the error
        }
```

Comment: `& $Service_Action $Service_Name`

Comment: Added. Getting error:  A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument for $Service_name

Comment: Please show full error message.

Comment: ```Attempting to perform the InitializeDefaultDrives operation on the 'FileSystem' provider failed.
Invoke-Command : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'service_name'.
At C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Source\Repos\xxxxxxx\Tests\get_status.ps1:32 char:15
+ Invoke-Command <<<<  -Session $sess -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlockContent -ArgumentList $Service_Action $Service_Name
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand```

Comment: `Invoke-Command ... -ArgumentList $Service_Action, $Service_Name`

Comment: Perfect!!!  I was missing it. Thanks a ton @PetSerAI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
## To run the script
# .\get_status.ps1 -Hostname <host> -Service_Action <action> -Service_Name <name>

#$Hostname = "hostname"
#$Service_Action = "Get-Service"
#$Service_Name = "service_name"

param(
    [string]$Hostname,
    [string]$Service_Action,
    [string]$Service_Name
)

$ScriptBlockContent = {
    param($Service_Action, $Service_Name)
    & $Service_Action $Service_Name
    }

# user credentials
$Username = "username"
$Password = "password"

# To avoid Manual entry of Username and Password
$Secure_String = convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force
$User_cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $Username, $Secure_String

# Create a Session
$pso = New-PSSessionOption -NoMachineProfile
$sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Hostname -SessionOption $pso -credential $User_cred

#Run a powershell script in the session.
Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlockContent -ArgumentList $Service_Action, $Service_Name

# Remove session
Remove-PSSession $sess`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 4):

You are passing your commands as strings to your function, so what you are syntactically doing with `$Service_Action $Service_Name` is to refer to two string objects in one line without any operator connecting them. That is the reason for the exception.

To tell powershell, that you want to execute a string as a command you have several options:

One option is to pass the commands as a single string to the `Invoke-Expression`cmdlet:

```
Invoke-Expression "$Service_Action $Service_Name"
```

Alternatively you can use the call-Operator `&`, which also tells powershell to treat a command as string. In this case you cannot give cmdlet and arguments in a single string, but in two:

```
& $Service_Action $Service_Name
```